# How To Include External Libraries in CMake Project

Tags: c++, cmake, sdl-2

I am confused on how to statically include the source code of SDL2. I am trying to do this to make a library I am working on more portable.

When I was setting this up as executable the library was compiled with it fine, but when I changed it to a library it wouldn't include the library.

Currently, when I try to include my library in another project it says **"Cannot open include file: 'SDL2/SDL.h': No such file or directory"**. So it leads me to think that the cause of the error is that the include directories aren't exported with the static library.

My Filesystem:

```
include
--Header Files
src
--Source Files
extern
--SDL2
build
```

Here is an example of the file causing the error:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL.h> //Error

using namespace std;

/* The code */
```

Here is an example of my main CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)

set(CMAKE_WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS ON)

project(MyProject VERSION 1.0.0)

set(SDL2_SOURCE_DIR “${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/extern/SDL2”)
add_subdirectory(extern/SDL2)
add_subdirectory(src)
```

Here is an example of my src CMakeLists.txt:

```
set(PROJECT_NAME MyProject)

file(GLOB HEADER_FILES "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include/*.h")
file(GLOB SOURCES "*.cpp")

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCES} ${HEADER_FILES})

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include" PUBLIC "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/extern/SDL2/include")

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE SDL2main SDL2-static)

set_target_properties( ${PROJECT_NAME}
    PROPERTIES
    ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib"
    LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib"
    RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/bin"
)
```

Comment: Please show full verbose output from the build command.

Answer (score 1):

From [sdl2 CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/spurious/SDL-mirror/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt#L2183) try:

```
set(SDL_STATIC 1)
add_subdirectory(extern/SDL2) # And I recommend EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL
```

Also to be sure add a check:

```
 foreach(i IN ITEMS SDL2main SDL2-static)
    if(NOT TARGET ${i})
       message(FATAL_ERROR "${i} is not a target")
     endif()
 endif()
 target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE SDL2main SDL2-static)
```

Comment: I tried to SDL_STATIC to 1, but I got the same error **"Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error C1083 Cannot open include file: 'SDL.h': No such file or directory"**. Also the check didn't work it wouldn't compile. Just adding but the code would compile when I was making a executable, but when I changed it to a library it failed.

Comment: @YamiOG Does `SDL.h` actually exist at the include path you provided: `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/extern/SDL2/include` ??

Comment: Yea it does have SDL.h. The code works when I am making a executable, but not when I am making a library.